# CSS animation keeps repeating

Tags: html, css

**SOLVED**

I wanted to slide an image to the top of the web page when I clicked on it, but that kept repeating. With the help of **jdwallace12** and [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/) I solved my question by adding the jQuery code below and `-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;`

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<img id="slideFromBottom" src="..." alt="image">
```

CSS

```
#footer a:active img {
    animation-name: slideFromBottom;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromBottom;animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;visibility: visible !important;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes slideFromBottom {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-1800%);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideFromBottom {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-1800%);}
}
```

JQUERY

```
$("#slideFromBottom").click(function() {
    this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";

    $(this).on('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        this.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
    });

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that, make a class for animation and add it to your image like

```
   .myClass{
      animation-name: slideFromBottom;
      -webkit-animation-name: slideFromBottom;animation-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;animation-timing-function: ease;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;visibility: visible !important;
    }

    $(".myClass").click(function() {          
       var el = $(this),  
       newone = el.clone(true); 
       el.before(newone);
       $("." + el.attr("class") + ":last").remove();
    });
```

Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/bvg6h/)

Comment: And how exactly do you do this?

Comment: I have added a link of demo, you can refer it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
animation-iteration-count: 1;
```

or try

```
$(function() {
  $("#name_of_id").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);

    el.before( el.clone(true) ).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: that helped, thanks! But when I click the image a second time the animation won't work anymore..

Comment: You will probably need some jquery to make this happen take a look at
[css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that or perhaps a hover state which requires no jQuery

```
.animate-img {
  animation-name: slideFromBottom;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideFromBottom;animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;visibility: visible !important;
}

$('img').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('animate-img');       
}
```